# Issue During Find Data From XML Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

i have XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<childrens>
  <child id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
    <child id="2" value="Apparel" parent_id="1">
      <child id="4" value="Shirts" parent_id="2"/>
      <child id="5" value="Pants" parent_id="2"/>
    </child>
    <child id="3" value="Accessories" parent_id="1">
      <child id="6" value="Handbags" parent_id="3"/>
      <child id="7" value="Jewelry" parent_id="3"/>
    </child>
     .
     .
     .
    <child id='bla bla'>
       <child id='bla bla'>
           <child id="1005" value="test1" parent_is="1111"/>
           <child id="1006" value="test12" parent_is="1111"/>
           <child id="1007" value="test123" parent_is="1111"/>
        <child>
    </child>
  <child >
</childrens>
```

i have written this jQuery code to get the leaf element(which has no child) for example here leaf node is which have id 4,5,6,7,1005,1006 and 1007

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('child').children().each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
            alert(id)
        });
    }
});
```

it is not working

Comment: Can you clarify what "not working" means? Is it not producing any alerts, not the expected number, not the correct value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select only the `child` elements that are "leaf nodes" and do not have any children, you can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector and change your selection to:

```
find('child:empty')
```

and then iterate over the selected elements, rather than it's children by removing `.children()`

Your example XML does not have any attributes called `entity_id`. For the example XML you would select `attr('id')`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('child:empty').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id)
        });
    }
});
```